# node.js async/sync with For Loop, Query, and Additional function

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, synchronization, async.js

Hello I am having an issue with the following sequence, I need to run multiple queries which build on each other that are in a for loop then once the final result is obtained to implement the result. I am having an issue where my for loop is looping past the query, also I need to stop the code while the findX function is running.

I know this is an async problem but I don't see how I could chain promises, or use the async npm package with needing to loop queries that depend on the result of the previous query. Thanks in advance.

```
    function findX(){
      //executes another query
    }

function solve(res, connection, info, requestArr, callback){

        var parentID = null;
        var obj = {};

        for (var i = 0; i <= requestArr.length; i++) {

          connection.query("SELECT WHERE ", [parentID, requestArr[i]], function(err, results) {
            if(results[0]['x']){
              var obj =  findX(x)
              break;
            }else{
                 parentID = results[0]['parentID'];
            }
          });
        }

    //Do stuff with obj only after the final result has been set in the for loop
      }
```

Comment: Look into `async/series` http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#series

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Async TimesSeries](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#timesSeries).

```
// Pretend this is some complicated async factory
var createUser = function(id, callback) {
    callback(null, {
        id: 'user' + id
    });
};

// generate 5 users
async.times(5, function(n, next) {
    createUser(n, function(err, user) {
        next(err, user);
    });
}, function(err, users) {
    // we should now have 5 users
});
```

---

So, in your example would be something like this:

```
var iterations = requestArr.length - 1,
    parentID,
    obj;

var getResults = function (i, callback) {
    connection.query("SELECT WHERE ", [parentID, requestArr[i]], function (err, results) {
        if (results[0]['x']) {
            obj = findX(x);
            callback('done');
        }

        else {
            parentID = results[0]['parentID'];
            callback();
        }
    });
};

async.timesSeries(iterations, function (n, next) {
    getResults(n, function (err) {
        next(err);
    });
}, function (err) {
    // use obj
});
```

Comment: would I then get the result of the findX within the query callback function in another callback wrapper or promise?